# Temporary Modified Environment during External Process Call from Emacs

Tags: shell, emacs, environment-variables, temporary, convenience-methods

Is there a *convenient* and *functional* (`with-...`-like) way of *temporary* modifying environment variables when using `shell-comand` or `start-process`?

Thanks in advance,
Per

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`server-with-environment` looks promising.

> server-with-environment is a Lisp macro in `server.el'.
>
> (server-with-environment ENV VARS &rest BODY)
>
> Evaluate BODY with environment variables VARS set to those in ENV.
>   The environment variables are then restored to their previous values.
>
> VARS should be a list of strings.
>   ENV should be in the same format as `process-environment'.

Answer (score 8):

*process-environment* is a
*List of overridden environment variables for subprocesses to inherit.*

```
(let ((process-environment (cons "FOO=BAR" process-environment)))
  (shell-command-to-string "echo $FOO"))
```

->

```
BAR
```