# Emacs: unifying citations between html and latex in org-mode

Tags: html, emacs, latex, org-mode

How to set up org-mode so it could include the *result* of `\cite` LaTeX command in HTML export?

Example:

```
Gulliver's Travels

My father had a small estate in Nottinghamshire: I was
the third of five sons.\cite{swift1726}

\printbibliography

#+LaTeX_HEADER: \usepackage{biblatex}
#+LaTeX_HEADER: \bibliography{classics}
```

LaTeX export is absolutely great. But HTML expectantly produce all citations as they are in source. But how to achieve an output like this:

```
...
<title>Gulliver's Travels</title>
...
<p>My father had a small estate in Nottinghamshire: I was
the third of five sons.[<a href="#swift1726">1</a>]</p>
...
<p id="swift1726">[1] J. Swift. <i>Gulliver's Travels</i>. 1726.</p>
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The [org-mode contributed package](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib) [`org-exp-bibtex.el`](http://repo.or.cz/w/org-mode.git?a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/org-exp-bibtex.el;hb=HEAD) produces an HTML bibliography using [bibtex2html](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) and then turns cite commands into links to bibliography items when you export to HTML. There is some documentation in [`org-exp-bibtex.el`](http://repo.or.cz/w/org-mode.git?a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/org-exp-bibtex.el;hb=HEAD).

I will include some additional information that helped me get this feature to work on my system. The file `org-exp-bibtex.el` seems to come with recent versions of org mode. So export may just work if you evaluate `(require 'org-exp-bibtex)` by, for instance, putting it in your `~/.emacs` and then put something like `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: classics plain` in your source file in the place of your LaTeX `\bibliographystyle` and `\bibliography` commands. I found the following patch to `org-exp-bibtex.el` was needed for my system though.

```
--- /usr/share/emacs/site-lisp/org_contrib/lisp/org-exp-bibtex.el   2011-08-09  7:39:35.000000000 -0500
+++ /home/who/.emacs.d/site-lisp/org-exp-bibtex.el  2011-09-06 20:34:55.000000000 -0500
@@ -56,6 +56,7 @@
 ;; 2) creates a foo.html and foo_bib.html
 ;; 3) includes the contents of foo.html in the exported html file

+(require 'cl)
 (require 'org)
 (require 'org-exp)

@@ -90,11 +91,13 @@
        (setq tmp-files   (cons tmp tmp-files))
        (setq extra-args (append extra-args `("-citefile" ,tmp)))))

-       (when (not (eq 0 (apply 'call-process  (append '("bibtex2html" nil nil nil)
+            (let ((process-environment (copy-alist process-environment)))
+              (setenv "TMPDIR" ".")
+             (when (not (eq 0 (apply 'call-process  (append '("bibtex2html" nil nil nil)
                               `("-a" "--nodoc"  "--style" ,style "--no-header")
                               extra-args
                               (list (concat file ".bib"))))))
-         (error "Executing bibtex2html failed"))
+         (error "Executing bibtex2html failed")))

            (dolist (f tmp-files) (delete-file f)))
```

The first change helps if you get the error "Symbol's function definition is void: flet", I learned [here](http://osdir.com/ml/emacs-orgmode-gnu/2010-02/msg00066.html). The second change just calls bibtex2html with TMPDIR set to the current directory. The [bibtex2html homepage](http://www.lri.fr/~filliatr/bibtex2html/) suggests such a workaround for a problem that bibtex2html has with some TeX installations.

Comment: Would you mind regenerating this patch with `diff -u` instead of just `diff`?

Comment: @Zack, just regenerated the patch as requested.

Comment: Thanks! Much easier to understand the change you made this way.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I hope it will be helpful for others. I just get `progn: Executing bibtex2html failed` error.

Comment: @Anton, I was getting the same error before I made the second change that is in the patch. As you can see in the patch, this error comes up when the bibtex2html command fails, so you may want to see if you can run bibtex2html by itself on the command line.

Comment: @e3bo, I do get `Forbidden to open for writing` from bibtex2html in command line but `setenv` seems to be not very helpful in Windows. I also rewrote `("-a" "-nodoc"  "-s" ,style "-noheader")` (according to `bibtex2html.exe -h`) and still without success.

Comment: I found that `bibtex2html` for Windows just ignores `TMPDIR`. It prefers `TEMP` environment. When this environment is set to `.` in System Properties and `org-exp-bibtex.el` has not been modified, bibtex2html does its job. With `setenv` modifications (rewritten to `(setenv "TEMP" ".")`, Emacs says `let: Args out of range: 0, 5`. The second point is that ODT export doesn't work with `org-exp-bibtex` (`let: Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`).

Comment: If you tried the patch above but no luck, maybe simply using `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: classics` or `#+BIBLIOGRAPHY: plain` can eliminate your error. At least this works for my case.

Comment: Note that the package changed name and is now calld `ox-bibtex` http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/ Raw file: http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/ox-bibtex.el;hb=HEAD

Answer (score 3):

e3bo's answer is excellent and covers all of what the original question asks for. I, however, was unable to obtain the desired results from the patch posted. I receive the `Args out of range` error noted by Anton in the comments to e3bo's answer. Below is a different implementation of e3bo's patch derived from one of the answers to [a separate, unrelated, question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483875/temporary-modified-environment-during-external-process-call-from-emacs). I can't say I know why this patch works for me and e3bo's doesn't; they're not particularly different from each other. At any rate, I've posted the patch in the hopes that it may solve problems experienced by users unable to get `bibtex2html` properly through other means.

```
--- org-exp-bibtex.el.orig      2013-01-05 15:00:53.000000000 -0600
+++ org-exp-bibtex.el   2013-01-05 16:34:54.000000000 -0600
@@ -89,12 +89,13 @@
                (with-temp-file tmp (dolist (i cite-list) (insert (concat i "\n"))))
                (setq tmp-files   (cons tmp tmp-files))
                (setq extra-args (append extra-args `("-citefile" ,tmp)))))
-
-           (when (not (eq 0 (apply 'call-process  (append '("bibtex2html" nil nil nil)
+           
+           (let ((process-environment (cons "TMPDIR=." process-environment)))
+             (when (not (eq 0 (apply 'call-process  (append '("bibtex2html" nil nil nil)
                                                           `("-a" "--nodoc"  "--style" ,style "--no-header")
                                                           extra-args
                                                           (list (concat file ".bib"))))))
-             (error "Executing bibtex2html failed"))
+             (error "Executing bibtex2html failed")))

            (dolist (f tmp-files) (delete-file f)))
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the Args out of range as well... this helped!

Answer (score 3):

The contributed package referred to in e3bo's answer has changed its name to [`ox-bibtex.el`](http://orgmode.org/w/?p=org-mode.git;a=blob_plain;f=contrib/lisp/ox-bibtex.el;hb=HEAD) (see also its entry in the [list of Org mode's contributed packages](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/)). Usage remains the same. However, now the line inserted in `~/.emacs` must be `(require 'ox-bibtex)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is recent support now for [ebib](http://ebib.sourceforge.net) in org-mode which works at least with its development version at the time of writing this reply.

Steps:

1. make sure ebib-preload-bib-files is set properly in your document so that your .bib file is loaded by ebib when ebib starts
2. add the following to your .emacs: `(org-add-link-type "ebib" 'ebib)`
3. insert ebib links in your documents like this: `[ebib:Jones1998][some paper title]`